# Javascript Happy Numbers not working

Tags: javascript, math

Here I have a function that should take a number `n` into the `disHappy(n)`  to check if all
`n in [n-0`)  are happy.

[Happy Numbers wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number)

If I only run `happyChecker(n)`, I can tell that 7 is happy, but `disHappy(n)` doesn't show it. It is as if it doesn't receive the true. I have used `console.log()'s` all over the place and happyChecker(n) shows a number that SHOULD return true. When I placed a `console.log()` above the `return true;` for `if(newNum===1)`, it showed that it branched into that branch but it just didn't seem to return the true.

```
  function happyChecker(n) {
     var arr = [];
     var newNum = 0;
     //here I split a number into a string then into an array of strings//
     num = n.toString().split("");
     for (var i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
         arr[i] = parseInt(num[i], 10);
     }
     //here I square each number then add it to newNum//
     for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
         newNum += Math.pow(arr[i], 2);
     }
     //here I noticed that all unhappy numbers eventually came into one of these three//
     //( and more) numbers, so I chose them to shorten the checking. A temporary solution for sure//       
     if (newNum === 58 || newNum === 4 || newNum == 37) {
         return false;
     }

     if (newNum === 1) {

         return true;
     } else {
         happyChecker(newNum);
     }

 }

 function disHappy(num) {
     for (j = num; j > 0; j--) {
         if (happyChecker(j)) {
             console.log(j + " is a Happy Number. It's so happy!!!.");
         }
     }
  }
```

Comment: You need to debug this using either your browser developer tools or worst case some alert boxes. My suggestion would be to put an alert box on each iteration of the algorithm and compare it to a known sequence. Check for infinite loops and check for incorrect values being calculated

Comment: did you miss the closing curly bracket for disHappy? if I add the bracket. and I call the function disHappy(7), here's the result: 1 is a Happy Number. It's so happy!!!.

Comment: @Larry in my program I didn't, but it must have gotten lost in pasting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you recurse, you need to `return` the value returned:

```
 if (newNum === 1) {

     return true;
 } else {
     return happyChecker(newNum);
 }
```

You also should declare "num" with `var`.

I'm ordinarily not a "code golfer", but this is a good example of how the (new-ish) iterator utility methods on the Array prototype can clean up code. You can use the `.reduce()` function to traverse the array of digit characters and do the work of squaring and summing all at once:

```
var newNum = n.toString()
              .split('')
              .reduce(function(sum, digit) {
                return sum + (+digit * +digit);
               }, 0);
```

The call to `.toString()` returns a string, then `.split('')` gives you an array. Then `.reduce()` starts with an initial sum of 0 and for each element of the array (each digit), it adds to it the square of that digit. (Instead of `parseInt()` I just used the `+` unary operator; we know for sure that each string will be a valid number and an integer.)

Comment: oh.... thats not too hard and it works!!! Thanks!!! Still don't know why it worked with 1,10 etc, but not 7.

Comment: @ChrisJones because for 1 and 10 the sum of squares is 1, so the first `return true;` path is taken.

Comment: oh OH.. I see.. so for some reason.. unless it went through on the first go through, it wouldn't return true even if it branches that way... interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add return to the happyChecker call.

```
return happyChecker(newNum);
```

see:

http://jsfiddle.net/YjgL8/2/

Answer (score 0):

here is my implementation

```js
var getSum = function (n) {
    if (!n >= 0) return -1;
    var digits = n.toString().split("");
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
        var digit = parseInt(digits[i], 10);
        sum += digit * digit;
    }
    return sum;
}

/**
 * @param {number} n
 * @return {boolean}
 */
var isHappy = function(n, visited) {
    if (n < 0) return false;
    if (n === 1) return true;
    if (typeof visited === 'undefined') visited = {};
    sum = getSum(n);
    if (visited[sum]) return false; // cycle
    visited[sum] = true;
    return isHappy(sum, visited);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete Example of finding happy numbers in range of custom number.

```js
        function happyNumbers() {
            var result = document.getElementById("happy-result")
            var inputy = parseInt(document.getElementById("happyValue").value)
            result.innerHTML=""
            for (i = 1; i < inputy; i++) {

               (happy(i, i)) 
                 
            }

        }

        function happy(value,value2) {
            var result = document.getElementById("happy-result")
            var lengthNum = value.toString().length;
            var resultNumbers = 0

            for (var b = 0 ; b < lengthNum; b++) {

                resultNumbers = resultNumbers + parseInt(value.toString().charAt(b)) * parseInt(value.toString().charAt(b))

            }
           
            if (resultNumbers == 4) {
                return false
            } else if (resultNumbers == 1) {
                result.innerHTML += "<br> happy number  " + i
                return true
            }else{
                happy(resultNumbers, value2);
            }

        }
        
        window.onload=happyNumbers()
```

```html
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">   
      <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">happy numbers</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <label>Enter the number that you want ot have see happy numbers uo to it</label>
                <input id="happyValue" oninput="happyNumbers()" value="100" class="form-control" />
                <div id="happy-result"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```