# Check whether given number is happy or not

Tags: javascript, number-theory

This is my code to check given number is a [Happy number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number). I think I am trying wrong logic.

```js
var num = 5239;
var sum = 0;
while (num > 0) {
  sum += Math.pow(num % 10, 2);
  num = Math.floor(num / 10);
  console.log(num)
}
console.log(sum);
if (num == 0) {
  alert("happy number")
} else {
  alert("Not happy number")
}
```

Please correct me to get correct result.

Comment: Logic is not correct. Calculate num using mod (%) function.

Comment: please this one https://gist.github.com/xk/8918502

Comment: Here: http://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-conditional-statements-and-loops-exercise-8.php

Comment: - what is a 'happy number'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45612451/2931256 check here the complete implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/g18tsjjx/1/

If i understood what happy number is, this should be correct.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var num = 1;
  var i = 0;
  for (i; i < 10000; i++) {
    num = newNumber(num);
  }
  num == 1 ? alert("it's happy number") : alert("it's not happy number");
});

function newNumber(num) {
  var sum = 0;
  var temp = 0;
  while (num != 0) {
    temp = num % 10;
    num = (num - temp) / 10;
    sum += temp * temp;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: Small correction in your code : Place `if-else` condition outside of the `for()loop`.

Answer (score 1):

According to wikipedia

> A happy number is a number defined by the following process: Starting
>   with any positive integer, replace the number by the sum of the
>   squares of its digits, and repeat the process until the number either
>   equals 1 (where it will stay), or it loops endlessly in a cycle that
>   does not include 1. Those numbers for which this process ends in 1 are
>   happy numbers, while those that do not end in 1 are unhappy numbers
>   (or sad numbers). [wikipedia Happy number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number)

I created recursive function `isHappy` to which we will pass our **number**,so
taking into the account **Happy Number** definition  and that javascript will trow  **Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded** when we will endlessly loop , we will put  function inside of *try...catch* block , So here is final Code

```
//Our Recursive Function
function isHappy(number){

   var output = [],
   sNumber = number.toString();

for (var i = 0, len = sNumber.length; i < len; i += 1) {

    output.push(+sNumber.charAt(i));//converting into number 

  }
  var sum=0;

for(var i=0;i<output.length;i++){
    sum+=Math.pow(output[i],2);
   }

if(sum!==1){
  isHappy(sum);

  }

}



 try{
      isHappy(number);//call the function with given number 
      alert('happy')

    }catch(err){
    alert('unhappy')
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I just came across happy numbers today in a job interview.
Here's the solution I came up with.

Even though I use recursion, using the set of seen numbers should prevent a stack overflow (and a potential endless loop in some cases).

```js
'use strict';

function happyNumber(n, unluckySet = new Set()) {
  const digitChars = n.toString().split('');
  let sum = 0;
  digitChars.forEach( digitChar => {
    sum += Math.pow(Number.parseInt(digitChar), 2);
  });
  if (sum === 1) return true; // lucky!
  if (unluckySet.has(sum)) return false; // we're unlucky
  unluckySet.add(sum);
  return happyNumber(sum, unluckySet);
}

// print all happy numbers in range 0..100
for (let i = 0; i <= 100; ++i) {
  if (happyNumber(i)) console.log(`${i} is a happy number`);
}

// this still should not cause a stack overflow
const largeHappyNum = 1234567894;
console.log(largeHappyNum, 'is happy:', happyNumber(largeHappyNum));
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [@Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12676003/6904888) expound, I created a JS version:

```js
function isHappy(n) {
  const next = (n) => {
    let ret = 0;
    for (const digit of `${n}`) {
      ret += (+digit) ** 2;
    }
    return ret;
  };
  while (n !== 1 && n !== 4) n = next(n);
  return n === 1;
}

console.log(isHappy(5239));
console.log(isHappy(19));
```

Answer (score 0):

I fear you are misreading the condition: it should first of all check for the final number being `=== 1`.

And you should not proceed with just an iteration, but go on until you either reach 1 or meet an already parsed number. I would recommend using a hash to keep track of the already `seen` numbers.

Just not to do some homework for free, a nice example with recursion [here](https://repl.it/JhY0).

Answer (score 0):

> this is code for any number. like number can be 3,4,5,6,7,8,9 digits. code helps you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title> Happy number</title>
<head>
<script>
function fun(){

var input = document.myform.t1.value;
do{

var output = [];
var sNumber = input.toString();
var len = sNumber.length;

var sum = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) 
{
    output.push(+sNumber.charAt(i));
}


var j;
var ret= [];
var outlen = output.length;
    for (j = 0; j < outlen; j++) 
    {
        ret.push(output[j] * output[j]);
    }
    
var sum = ret.reduce(getSum);
     
input = sum;

}while(input >= 9);

if(input == 1)
{
document.getElementById("para1").innerHTML = (" given number is happynumber");
}
else
{ 
document.getElementById("para1").innerHTML = ("not happy number");
}
}
function getSum(total, num) {
    return total + num;}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<form name="myform" method="post" onsubmit="fun(); return false;">

<table border="1">

<tr>
<th colspan="2"> Happy Number </th>  
</tr>

<tr>
<th> input number : </th>
<td> <input type="text" name="t1" id="text1" pattern="[0-9]{2,}" title="only numbers allowed" ></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2"> <center><button onclick="fun()">alert</button></center></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2"> <center>  <p id="para1"  style="color:red;"> </p> </center></td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.